# Como personalizar a url amigavel com htaccess passando apenas o slug como parametro visível?

Tags: htaccess

Olá,

Procuro personalizar mais a url amigável desta forma `www.portalvidapet.com.br/radium-hotel-em-guarapari` sem precisar de passar algum outro parâmetro visível na url.

Para isso, tentei fazer o `.htaccess` da seguinte forma: `RewriteRule ^/([[a-z0-9-]+)/?$ texto.php?id=$1 [NC]` , porém, dá erro 404.

Se eu fizer `RewriteRule ^artigo/([[a-z0-9-]+)/?$ texto.php?id=$1 [NC]` funciona perfeitamente, só que eu não gostaria de utilizar o nome `artigo` na url, pois, gostaria de passar direto o `slug`.

Para ficar assim `www.portalvidapet.com.br/radium-hotel-em-guarapari`

Como resolver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que sua regra htaccess possuí um erro de sintaxe meu amigo.

Você fez :

> RewriteRule ^/([[a-z0-9-]+)/?$ texto.php?id=$1 [NC]

Está abrindo um [ sem fecha-lo, o certo seria:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)\/?$ texto.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

Ou seja qualquer url que inicie no intervalo contendo os caracteres de **a - z** , **0 até 9** e **-**. Podendo ter um ou mais caracteres precedido de barra ou não. Atribuir ao argumento **id** na página **texto.php**

Não se esqueça de usar barra invertida para uso de /. A barra é um carácter especial da expressão regular então devemos escapá-la. =)

Espero que isso lhe ajude!

Testando a regra:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Use a ferramenta de teste online:
https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: Funcionou muito bem, agora estou com um outro problema, como capturar dinamicamente o `id` da notícia via `htaccess`? Pois preciso desta informação para que a página `texto.php` me entregue o resultado correto.

Comment: Se está querendo acessar a variável que passou por parâmetro, basta usar a variável de escopo global $_GET['id'] para acessa-la dentro da pagina teste.php. Tente imprimi-la assim <?php echo $_GET['id']; ?> no topo da pagina.

Comment: Neste caso minha url ficará `www.portalvidapet.com.br/radium-hotel-em-guarapari` o ideal é se fazer busca pelo `slug`? Ou o correto é eu passar na url o parâmetro com o`id` e mais o `slug`?

Comment: As duas formas estão corretas. Mas atente-se que se for usar apenas o slug no seu banco de dados na tabela aonde salva seus posts o atributo slug da tabela tem que conter uma chave unique (única) para que não haja duplicação. Se optar por usar o slug deve ter uma rotina php para assim que acessar a página teste.php você carregue o id e outras informações necessárias através desse método. Mas isso é resposta para outra pergunta!